# Windows 8 delays asking for credentials

Tags: windows-8, credentials

This problem suddenly appeared on my domain-connected machine in the past few days (no significant installs or reconfigurations that I can think of). If I lock my computer, when I go to unlock it, I get a "Please wait" message with a spinning wheel. This lasts for 2-3 minutes before I am finally asked for my credentials.

The same happens if I attempt to use Remote Desktop Connection to another machine... 2-3 minutes of "just a moment...", then finally I am asked for my credentials.

Does anyone know of anything that would cause such behaviour (such as a Windows Update) and what I could do to solve it? It's quite unbearable having a mandatory wait period before doing anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know a specific resolution but here are some troubleshooting steps as it sounds like something with Kereberos and/or AD. 
     I would first ask if it happens to other users on their Win8 machines. If none, I would see if it takes that long when not connected to the LAN. If it logs in quickly using your cached credentials, (not on the LAN), then something changed on the domain. I would start by checking your DNS settings and making sure it matches other non problematic systems. Perhaps then try rejoining to the domain.